# My touchpad action is rotated 90 degrees

Tags: touchpad

I have no idea what happened but when I move my fingers on the touchpad  up and down the mouse pointer scrolls left to right instead and when I scroll left to right it scrolls up and down. How do I fix this?

Comment: somebody has reversed your  touch pad action

Comment: Rotate your laptop 90 degrees and try again.

Answer (score 2):

For Synaptics (and some derived) touchpads and pointing sticks, a bit of
digging through the registry turned up persistent, per-user, axis rotation
angles and a per-system, auto-rotation control.

Applying the following patch, either immediately before logging
out (and back in) logging out reverts the axes and leaves them so.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\StickPS2]
"MotionRotationAngle"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\TouchPadPS2]
"MotionRotationAngle"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPEnh]
"AutoRotationFlag"=dword:00000000
```

*Applying the patch either between killing and restarting 'SynTpEnh.exe' (per
user) or just before entering or leaving the touchpad control panel may also
work (less disruptively), but remains untested.*

**As always, save the original values before applying the patch--especially
the autorotation flag, which is OEM dependent and not documented in the
Synapitcs reference driver release notes.**

Answer (score 0):

Aaron Miller's comment pointed me to a solution.  I had the same problem with inverted axis for my Elan touchpad.

I went to Screen Resolution Settings, and switched the Orientation from Landscape to Portrait, and then to Landscape again. And now it's fixed.

It seems that when I used an external device that had mouse tracking included (Virtual Reality Headset), I changed the orientation to Portrait for that device, but when I unplugged it, Windows didn't return to Landscape orientation, leaving me with the mouse pad on Portrait.