# Portrait primary display rotates touchpad

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, touchpad

I have Windows 7 64bit on a Lenovo T530 laptop (1600x900) with a Lenovo ThinkVision LT2452p monitor (1920x1200). I set up screen resolution like this:

- Compose displays.
- Set the primary display to LT2452p monitor.
- Set the LT2452p monitor to portrait.

Effects:

- Task bar is on the LT2452p monitor (exactly what I wanted). Minitor orientation is correct.
- Attached USB Mouse moves correctly.
- Touch pad directions are rotated 90 degrees. Moving up moves to cursor right. Moving right moves the cursor down.
- Mini joystick is rotated like the touchpad.

I browsed through the touch pad settings ("UltraNav" tab at mouse properties) but did not find any rotation options. It is not allowed to install any solutions from John Doe as it is a company laptop.

UPDATE: I also cannot install unmaintained software like, EeeRotate or ScreenMouseRotate.

Comment: Are you using Synaptic?

Comment: @smc Not that I know of. Is is coming with something?

Comment: Check your task manager and see if syntpenh.exe is running

Comment: @smc I do have `SynTPEnh.exe` running.

Comment: try the following. Rotate both screens to normal orientation. Kill `SynTPEnh.exe` from task manager. Rotate the screen to portrait orientation. See if the touchpad behavior is as expected. Let me know what was the result.

Comment: @smc This worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

For Synaptics (and some derived) touchpads and pointing sticks, a bit of
digging through the registry turned up persistent, per-user, axis rotation
angles and a per-system, auto-rotation control.

Applying the following patch, either immediately before logging
out (and back in) logging out reverts the axes and leaves them so.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\StickPS2]
"MotionRotationAngle"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\TouchPadPS2]
"MotionRotationAngle"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPEnh]
"AutoRotationFlag"=dword:00000000
```

*Applying the patch either between killing and restarting 'SynTpEnh.exe' (per
user) or just before entering or leaving the touchpad control panel may also
work (less disruptively), but remains untested.*

**As always, save the original values before applying the patch--especially
the autorotation flag, which is OEM dependent and not documented in the
Synaptics reference driver release notes.**

Comment: Copied from my 29 April answer to [64629[[]https://superuser.com/questions/624629/], which was marked duplicate 30 April.  Replaces a previous answer downvoted (perhaps appropriately) for only referring to the other post.

Comment: Ordinarily, I would have preferred simply to edit the other answer, but the retained down-vote count would have been deceptive:  it reflected my having previously supplied a reference in lieu of this content (which, for the OP's apparent purposes, produces more useful results than other answers presented here.

Comment: Mine were in a slightly different spot (`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTP\TouchPadSMB2cTM3145-3

`), but searching the registry for those key names found them all. You should be able to stop the service `SynTPEnh Caller Service`, kill the `SynTpEnh.exe` process, and then restart the service.

Answer (score 1):

User **smc** in the comments above suggested kiilling the `SynTPEnh.exe` [Synaptec pointing driver] to fix the mouse issues.  While this works, it also breaks all TouchPad and UltraNav features.  I searched my drive for another copy and it turns out there was a version from 2010 on there.  Launched that and I got my scrolling back even with a vertical monitor!

If you plan on using a vertical monitor setup on a regular basis with Synaptec hardware, see if downgrading the driver is a viable option.

Another note: This issue only seems to come up when the **primary monitor** is in portrait mode.  If you don't want to downgrade, see if you can run your primary monitor horizontally and your secondary/tertiary/etc. monitor(s) vertically.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but the primary monitor (where the taskbar is and where the applications appear) "must" be portrait one. Unfortunately I cannot test your idea about downgrading because I don't have the hardware anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is rotating the display using the video-card graphics software.
Unfortunately, that solution doesn’t rotate anything else, meaning that your touchpad is still configured for standard, landscape usage.

So, if you rotate your desktop on a laptop, the touchpad will not rotate with the screen, which makes the touchpad somewhat difficult to use.

As Microsoft doesn't supply a solution, one needs to use third-party products.

The best recommended product I could find is [EeeRotate](https://sites.google.com/site/vkedwardli/eeerotate), last updated in 2008,
but might still work for you :

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>: rotate screen and touchpad by 270 degrees
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>: back to normal

A similar product is [ScreenMouseRotate](http://www.math.uaa.alaska.edu/~afkjm/techteach/?q=node/70), last updated in 20010.

(I have no personal experience with both products.)

Comment: "doesn't rotate anything else": false. The mouse works correctly on both screens (monitor and laptop). The touch-pad works rotated 90 degree clockwise on both screens. Both products you mention are abandonware, so I'm not allowed install them.

Comment: And also EeeRotate seems to rotate both monitors, while I want to rotate only one.

Comment: I'm using some excellent utilities that haven't been updated for years, but still work fine. I don't know of a product that rotates the touchpad as a function of the active monitor, but you could use the keyboard shortcuts to rotate/unrotate when needed. Not optimal, I agree.

Comment: Another remark: It is possible to write an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) macro that does what you want, to exchange the x,y coordinates of the mouse, and only when the active window is on the right monitor. [This thread](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/17828-invert-mouse-axis/) could get you started.